# Indicator is not rendering on iOS and Android

Tags: react-native

I am trying to render the topBar on tab navigation and it's not showing

```js
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Dashboard: {
      screen: Dashboard,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Dashboard",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon
            name="home"
            type="Entypo"
            style={{
              color: tintColor,
            }}
            color={tintColor}
          />
        ),
      },
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: "top",
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#5D10F6",
      inactiveTintColor: "gray",
      showIcon: true,
      tintColor: "#333",
      animationEnabled: false,
      showLabel: false,
      scrollEnabled: true,
      tabBarPosition: "top",
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "red",
      },
    },
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: createTabNavigator is removed in react-navigation@3.x. Please use createBottomTabNavigator and/or createMaterialTopTabNavigator instead.

However `createBottomTabNavigator` no longer supports indicatorStyle :(

Comment: for more [click me](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-navigator.html)